# Сделать подсказку input правильнее

Tags: html, css

Есть ли способ сделать неисчезаемую подсказку в input правильнее/профессиональнее для адаптивной верстки?

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0rvqLaak/1/)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.myinput {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  padding-left: 25px;
}

.ot {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: -325px;
  color: #ccc;
  font-style: italic;
}

.input-group {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-group">
  <input class="myinput" type="text" />
  <div class="ot">от</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Единственное я бы изменил div на span...  А так все верно решено

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо `div` использовать `label`, который устанавливает связь между определенной меткой и элементом формы.

Метка - в данной случае это текст в `label`

Элемент формы - `input`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.input-group {
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.myinput {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px 25px 5px 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

.mylabel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 15px;
  color: #ccc;
  font-style: italic;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-group">
  <input class="myinput" type="text" id="text" />
  <label class="mylabel" for="text">от</label>
</div>
```

Comment: То, что нужно. Спасибо)